# piCameraValueError : Incorrect buffer length for resolution 640x480

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, face-detection

I am trying to make my raspberry pi detect face(s) in video feed from pi camera, this is my code

```
import time
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera

# camera settings
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640,480))

time.sleep(1)

# video input 
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


# capture frame from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):

    image = frame.array

# face detection
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

#show the frames

        cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        rawCapture.truncate(0)

        if key == ord("q"):
            break
```

I tried to run it, but i got this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File"/home/pi/pythonpy/videofacedet/craft/videofacedet(selfmade).py", line 21, in <module>
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1702, in capture_continuous
if not encoder.wait(self.CAPTURE_TIMEOUT):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 395, in wait
self.stop()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 419, in stop
self._close_output()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 349, in _close_output
mo.close_stream(output, opened)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 371, in close_stream
stream.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 238, in flush
self.array = bytes_to_rgb(self.getvalue(), self.size or self.camera.resolution)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 127, in bytes_to_rgb
    'Incorrect buffer length for resolution %dx%d' % (width, height))
PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 640x480
```

where did it go wrong? I am new to python programming so I get confused about how can I fix it and where to start. Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't seem to be indented properly. I would suggest indenting these lines:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
```

to be indented the same as the line `image = frame.array`

I think that was the cause of the error since you're supposed to clear the current frame when you're done with it to prepare for the next frame and I see you're trying to do that with `rawCapture.truncate(0)`.

Indentation is really important in python since that's how lines of code are treated as blocks. I see it as how curly braces in some programming languages treat lines of code as blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the framerate you set is too high, I delete the line `camera.framerate= 32`,then the camera window showed in screen.